# I set up a successful reverse shell but my commands return nothing

Tags: netcat, reverse-shell

I recently successfully uploaded an msfvenom binary payload into a Windows server 2008 VM.

My netcat listener displays the following message:

```
connect to [lhost ip] from (UNKNOWN) [rhost ip] 49155
```

which means it is connected.

But when I run commands such as dir it doesn't output anything.
 What do you think is the problem?

Comment: How will netcat be able to interact with msf payload?

Comment: I generated a reverse tcp stager not a meterpreter shell payload

Comment: And it worked before

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by generating a different payload.

Payload that didn't work: `/windows/x64/shell/reverse_tcp`

Payload that worked: `/windows/x64/shell_reverse_tcp` (and adding some flags `-e x64/xor -i 5`)

Comment: If I remember correctly, they are 2 different kinds of payload in msf: staged and non-staged. Payload in the form `shell/reverse_tcp` are staged payloads and the one in the form `shell_reverse_tcp` are not. Staged payloads are smaller in size, but after the connection the second stage has to be sent to the victim. The non-staged payloads are bigger but "all in one". That would be why a staged payload isn't working with nc as a receiver: nc is not sending the second stage.